# Angularjs: Ui Grid: gridApi.edit.on.afterCellEdit with checkbox, datepickers or select item

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I need to use gridApi.edit.on.afterCellEdit but when a cell contains a checkbox or a datepicker and they are changed this function is not invoked and therefore it is imposible for the app to obtain the record updated.

How could I know when a record was modified (where the cell modified is a checkbox or any other object)?

Thank you in advance.